# Plugin clips do Redactor não insere o exato html

Tags: jquery

Estou testando o plugin **clips** do editor [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) para inserir trechos de código no meu editor.

Porém, ao tentar inserir um trecho de código seguindo alguns modelos do [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) o plugin ou o Redactor está alterando o html a ser inserido ("o clip"), exemplo:

**Esse é um dos clips:**

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="redactor_clip_link">Template 2 Colunas</a>

  <div class="redactor_clip" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Ao inserir ele, o retorno é o seguinte:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
        <h2>Digite o titulo aqui</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, sequi ea rerum minima dolor ratione cumque vero repellendus ipsam! Porro, quasi repellat modi. Doloremque, quis, error neque molestias fugit natus modi ducimus? Error, tenetur, rerum debitis ipsa aspernatur sed sequi.
</p>
```

Como podem ver, ele fechou todas as `<div>` acima do segundo `<h2>` e colocou o parágrafo no final do html. Porque? Não sei.

---

### Clips: função que faz a inserção do código html

```
insertClip: function(html)
  {
    this.selectionRestore();
    this.insertHtml($.trim(html));
    // this.insertHtmlAdvanced($.trim(html)); // doesn't work
    this.modalClose();
  }
```

---

### Redactor: chamada na view

```
  $('#PageDescription').redactor({
    minHeight: 300,
    plugins: ['clips'],
    convertDivs: false,
    lang: 'pt_br',
    deniedTags: ['h1'],
    buttons: ['html', '|', 'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'image', 'video', 'file', 'table', 'link', '|', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'horizontalrule'],
    imageUpload: '/admin/pages/upload_image',
    fileUpload: '/scripts/file_upload.php',
    keyupCallback: function (obj, event) {
      var max = $('#PageDescription').prop('maxlength');
      if (typeof max !== "undefined" && max > 0) {
        var current = obj.currentTarget.innerText.length;
        var $box = $('#PageDescription').parent(".redactor_box");
        var $redactor_indicator = $(".redactor_indicator", $box);
        if ($redactor_indicator.size() === 0) {
          $box.append($("<div class='redactor_indicator'><span class='current'>" + (current - 3) + "</span> of <span class='max'>" + max + "</span> caracteres restantes</div>"));
        } else {
          $(".current", $redactor_indicator).text(current - 3);
          $(".max", $redactor_indicator).text(max);
        }
        if (current >= max) {
          $box.css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
          $redactor_indicator.css("color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
          $box.css("border", "1px solid #DDDDDD");
          $redactor_indicator.css("color", "#000000");
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Encontrei o problema:** a função `insertHtml()` utilizada no clips, que faz parte da **API do Redactor** por algum motivo faz a alteração do meu HTML.

[Pesquisando na API](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/) encontrei a função `set()`, e ao usá-la no plugin (removendo a função `insertHtml()`, tudo funcionou como esperado.

```
  insertClip: function(html)
  {
    this.selectionRestore();
    this.set($.trim(html)); // <---- change insertHtml() to set()
    this.modalClose();
  }
```